# Why does this std::queue/list of pointers to structs not free memory until List.Size() == 0?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program that feeds pointers to structs containing cv::mat clones into a std::queue/std::list (tried both) that other threads consume.

Reading/creation is fast, but consuming is slow, so the queue grows in size over time.
This queue get huge, easily taking up >50% system memory.

When the reading/creation stops, the queue shrinks, but the memory doesn't!
When the queue size finally hits 0, the memory disappears almost instantly. The queue.size() == 0 trigger can be confirmed by making sure the queue never pops the last pointer--the memory will not disappear.
*Note: The queue still exists, it has not gone out of scope, which is static.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does the memory disappear when queue hits size zero? Or in other words, why doesn't the memory disappear as the pointers are consumed/deleted?
2. How can the memory be released explicitly?

---

The code is something like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    cv::mat matA;
    ~MyStruct(){
       cout << "Yeah, destructor is called!" << endl;
       //matA.release(); //Not needed, right? Adding it does not change anything.
    }
};

static queue<shared_ptr<MyStruct>> awaitingProcessing;
static mutex queueGuard;
```

Thread 1 (queue filler):

```
BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(dataWidth*dataHeight);
while(signal){
    LoadData(buffer);
    cv::Mat data = cv::Mat(dataHeight, dataWidth, CV_8U, buffer);
    
    auto addable = shared_ptr<MyStruct>(new MyStruct())>;
    addable->matA = data.clone();
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(queueGuard);
    awaitingProcessing.push(addable);

}
```

Thread 2 (consumer):

```
    shared_ptr<MyStruct> pullFromQueue(){
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(queueGuard);
        if (awaitingProcessing.size() > 0){
            auto returnable = awaitingProcessing.front();
            awaitingProcessing.pop();
            return returnable;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    void threadLogic(){
        while (!interruptFlag){
            auto ptr = pullFromQueue();
            if (ptr == nullptr){
                usleep(5);
            }
            else{
                doSomething(ptr);
            }
            // ptr destructor called here, as refcount properly hits zero
        } 

    }
```

---

If I recall correctly, std data collections often don't release their memory and hold it as reserve, in case the size grows again. However, this collection (queue and/or list) consists of pointers, so even if the queue gets large, the memory footprint should be small.

I'm not familiar with OpenCV's memory management, but it seems to be doing something similar. Pausing the queue filling allows the queue size to shrink, but the memory doesn't shrink. Then, resuming filling increases the queue size, without increasing memory size.

---

To summarize a few key points:

- Memory does get released without scope changing (ie not a memory leak)
- Memory ONLY releases when the queue size hits zero. It will not release if the queue size stays forever at 1
- The structs get destructed
- The structs contain cloned cv::mats (I think this is the key point)
- The list/queue only contains pointers and should thus be small

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. What is this line `auto addable = shared_ptr<new MyStruct()>;`? It looks like you've modified the code manually. But you need to show us the code as it is in order to analyze it. Otherwise it is possible that you've also removed a memory leak.

Comment: What's `v::Mat`? Is it supposed to be `cv::Mat`? AS far as I know, there is no `cv::Mat` constructor that takes a `std::shared_ptr<BYTE>`. Please post real code.

Comment: Your buffer seems a bit small. What's in `LoadData`?

Comment: How big the queue gets? How much memory you have?

Comment: @freakish Queue gets up to 500ish. The actual data is images, so this equates to a few GB held in the structs' mats

Comment: @molbdnilo Surely I can't be the first person who has posted about something they were not allowed to copy and paste? And sorry for missing your other question--I don't know what's in LoadData. It's an SDK

Answer (score 1):

`std::queue` uses a `std::deque` as the internal container by default. When memory is deallocated is implementation defined to a large extent(and which could be the case when the size hits zero), but `std::deque` and `std::vector` does have a function for freeing excess memory namely [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/shrink_to_fit) ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) feature). This is not available from the `std::queue` interface, but can be done with inheritance (the container in queue is `protected`).

*psudocode*:

```
template<class T>
struct shrinkable_queue : public std::queue<T> {
  void shrink_to_fit() {c.shrink_to_fit();}
};
```

---

You could also use a `std::queue<T, std::list<T>>`. I did check the MSVC implementation since you said you tried list as well and at least on my version it seems that it deallocates the memory even when removing single nodes (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I mentioned this feature towards the bottom of the post, but since the list/queue contain only pointers, I don't think the list/queue is what takes up memory. Can I ask which version of c++ you used? I should also probably specify (and check) by opencv version here...

Comment: c++17 VS2017, can dig out the compiler version but i don't see that as relevant

Comment: @Mars where/how do you check memory consumption ? you can never rely on OS reported numbers to be accurate of what your program are actually using (there are simply too much optimizations, etc. going on in the OS's)

Comment: OS is exactly how I'm measuring it (Ubuntu->top)

Comment: @Mars then how do you know if it's just buffered ? c++ level usually has internal buffer too (going to OS each time is expensive) ! (ie. until the OS decides to reclaim it)

Comment: hmm... i tried c++17 and still no difference. when you tried the MSVC version with list, were you allocating  structs and cv::mat clones?

Comment: I'll have to double check that it was "used" not "buffered," but even if this is the case, it seems very odd that the OS *only* claims it if/when the queue/list hits size 0

Comment: @Mars the only way I know to be certain is to use some kind of leak checker utility - or at minimum something that can report what is on the heap

Comment: @Mars On MSVC you could try with `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` with heap tracking enabled (despite the name, dumps what is currently on the heap) not sure what you would do in clang/gcc - which compiler/platform are you on ?

Comment: Ubuntu, g++. I'll look into checking the heap, but I'll be out of the office for a little while, so it will probably be a few days before I get back to you. Sorry!